# Find specific values and extract in Excel

Tags: excel, automation, ms-office

I am trying to automate a process, on where I need to search an Excel file to find specific values. Below is an example of an Excel file I get:

[image]

Now, the excel file contains all sorts of information. However, I only need to get below values (which can occurr on multiple pages). However, the setup is the same for all pages.

I need to get the "Tariff" number and the value for that tariff number, then add them all up. So, for example I would end up with this:

[image]

Is this even possible? And how would I go about this?

Comment: Because you say multiple pages, I think you need to use vba. I do not think you can use Vlookup on multiple pages.

Comment: @Andreas What if all the pages is consolidated into one sheet? Could VLOOKUP be used?

Comment: Yes, maybe. Depends on what the sheet will look like. But vlookup will find the searchword/number and grab the value you want from the same row.